# how can i use break in ruby on rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

what is the best way to not create/save if exist ? 
i have the following in my models

```
class Censu < ApplicationRecord
    before_create :check_if_exist


    def check_if_exist
       break if ItemsCensu.exists?(year: @year)
            puts  "Εχεις κανει απογραφη για την χρονια #{@year}"

    end
end
```

i try render :index but still not work, also break

if i put break i have the following error

**Invalid break**
so how can i stop the create if the year exist ? and put the puts message as an alert or error?

Comment: Use ItemsCensu.find_or_create_by(year: @year) in create method and no need for before_action check_if_exist.

Comment: Maybe use `validates_uniqueness_of :year`?

Answer (score 1):

just change break with return

```
class Censu < ApplicationRecord
    before_create :check_if_exist

    def check_if_exist
       return if ItemsCensu.exists?(year: @year)

       // your other code here
    end
end
```